# How to update environment variables through python code on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

What I'm trying to do is:

1. I'm trying to make a Telegram-bot that sends me a message when there's a new post updated on a specific web page.
2. I made the code and uploaded it on Heroku.
3. The bot is set to keep starting every 10 minutes using Heroku Scheduler so that it would detect any new post updated every 10 minutes.

Now the problem is:

1. The code is set to remember the latest post number and not to make any alarm if there's nothing updated between the previous bot run and the current run.
2. If the saved post number in the previous run matches the latest post number in the present run, the bot should not alarm me and keep doing the scheduled process (keep checking new posts every 10 minutes).
3. This is what I made to make this work

   ```
   import os

   latest_num = os.environ.get("POST_ID")

   post_num = posts.find("td", {"class" : "no"}).text.strip()

   if latest_num != post_num :
     latest_num = post_num
     os.environ["POST_ID"] = latest_num
   ```
4. I assume that if the latest post number from the previous run is saved as "POST_ID" through environment variables on Heroku, it should appear in the present run and be the value of `latest_num` when using `os.environ` to read `"POST_ID"` from the environment variable.
5. But the problem is, it seems like `os.environ["POST_ID"]` doesn't overwrite its value after the current run is done. Every time the Heroku scheduler starts the program, the `'latest_num'` value is `0`, the same as the default value of `"POST_ID"` on Heroku's settings.
6. So, even though there's no new post, the bot keeps sending me a message because `'latest_num'` doesn't match `'post_num'` all the time.

How can I fix this? Actually, I don't know whether setting environment variables through python code is possible or not. Please tell me if there's something better to make this work.

Comment: Why you aren't saving the previous post number in text file or in python variable?

Comment: Oh that was something that i couldn't imagine. im going to try that right now. Thank you!

Comment: Did you set the original env var value using Heroku's [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)? Can't verify it now, but Heroku dynos get regularly restarted and "*Config var values are persistent–they remain in place across deploys and app restarts.*". My guess is your dyno restarted and your app's env resets to the original value.

Comment: A text file won't work either because Heroku dynos file system are ephemeral: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted ("*These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for persistent storage of data*")

Comment: I suggest using Heroku's database solutions to persist the updated value

Comment: I don't think OP should use "database" just to save 10/20 word/letter.

Comment: @Kshitiz It is excessive, yes. But files and env vars are not persistent, since Heroku dynos regularly restart.

Comment: Does that really delete that file, while doing that? Because I am also doing the same thing but my files aren't missing!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As the strorage of Heroku is ephemeral, i couldn't save the changed post_id in txt files. After some tries, I've just figured out that a service called PostgreSQL could be used as database to save the variable data. So I'm testing this method and I think this is working very well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save those previous `post id` either in text file or in `python variable`. I prefer to save it in text file because if you restart or close your program then it forget all previous stuff but it isn't for text file.
Here's the code: At first while saving do this:

```
post_num = posts.find("td", {"class" : "no"}).text.strip()
with open("pre.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(post_num)
```

And now your scrape scrape second time then do this:

```
post_num = posts.find("td", {"class" : "no"}).text.strip()
with open("pre.txt","rb") as f:
    pre_num=f.read()
if post_num!=pre_num:
    #Do Something 
    with open("pre.txt","wb") as f:
        f.write(post_num)
else:
    #Do something
```

Comment: Heroku's file system is ephemeral https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted: "*The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a process known as "Cycling".*"